# What does the colon mean in Stan?

Tags: stan, rstan

I'm brand new at programming in Stan, and trying to work through some code that I found on the web:
https://modernstatisticalworkflow.blogspot.com/2017/11/bayesian-instrumental-variables-with.html

```
data {
  int N;
  int PX; // dimension of exogenous covariates
  int PN; // dimension of endogenous covariates
  int PZ; // dimension of instruments
  matrix[N, PX] X_exog; // exogenous covariates
  matrix[N, PN] X_endog; // engogenous covariates
  matrix[N, PZ] Z; // instruments
  vector[N] Y_outcome; // outcome variable
  int<lower=0,upper=1> run_estimation; // simulate (0) or estimate (1)
}
transformed data {
  matrix[N, 1 + PN] Y;
  Y[,1] = Y_outcome;
  Y[,2:] = X_endog;
}
parameters {
  vector[PX + PN] gamma1;
  matrix[PX + PZ, PN] gamma2;
  vector[PN + 1] alpha;
  vector<lower = 0>[1 + PN] scale;
  cholesky_factor_corr[1 + PN] L_Omega;
}
transformed parameters {
  matrix[N, 1 + PN] mu; // the conditional means of the process

  mu[:,1] = rep_vector(alpha[1], N) + append_col(X_endog,X_exog)*gamma1;
  mu[:,2:] = rep_matrix(alpha[2:]', N) + append_col(X_exog, Z)*gamma2;

}
```

This is the start to an instrumental variables model. In the "transformed parameters" section, I'm not exactly sure what the ":" is doing in the lines:

```
 mu[:,1] = rep_vector(alpha[1], N) + append_col(X_endog,X_exog)*gamma1;
  mu[:,2:] = rep_matrix(alpha[2:]', N) + append_col(X_exog, Z)*gamma2;
```

Does it tell Stan that this should iterate over the existing rows/columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, a colon indicates a sequence of consecutive integers (unless it is used as part of a ternary operator). Usually, you will see it with integers on both sides of the color, such as `for (n in 1:N) {...}`. However, section 27.2 of the Stan User Manual describes subsetting arrays, vectors, matrices, etc. with "one-sided" integer sequences as

> It is also possible to supply just a lower bound, or just an upper bound. Writing `c[3:]` is just shorthand for `c[3:size(c)]`. Writing `c[:5]` is just shorthand for `c[1:5]`.

Also, the Stan User Manual describes subsetting with "zero-sided" integer sequences as

> Finally, it is possible to write a range index that covers the entire range of an array, either by including just the range symbol (`:`) as the index or leaving the index position empty. In both cases, `c[]` and `c[:]` are equal to `c[1:size(c)]`, which in turn is just equal to `c`.

So, `mu[:,2:] =` is equivalent to `mu[ , 2:cols(mu)] =` and fills all rows for all but the first column with the (sub)matrix on the right-hand side of the assignment operator.